# Cómo asegurar que los layouts de una app se vean de forma correcta y con el mismo aspecto en cualquier dispositivo Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

El tema es que estoy probando una app que he hecho en distintos teléfonos, y el aspecto de las interfaces varía en los distintos dispositivos, y en algunos se ven los elementos bien ordenados mientras en otros los elementos aparecen más desordenados o incluso algún elemento que incomprensiblemente no se muestra...

Estoy mirando de crear nuevos directorios dentro de la carpeta res de mi proyecto, para manejar distintas densidades y tamaños de pantalla, pero no tengo muy claro cuántos crear....

Ahora mismo como directorios tengo layout y otro layout-land.

Estaba pensando en añadir los siguientes directorios: layout-small, layout-large, layout-xlarge, layout-ldpi, layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi, layout-xxhdpi, layout-xxxhdpi.
Mi app consta de 9 layouts, osea sería meter esos 9 layouts en cada una de las carpetas mencionadas anteriormente, y luego adecuar el diseño para cada una de esas carpetas...

Aunque igual sería pasarse de la raya y no necesito tantas carpetas distintas, y es lo que no tengo claro, y por eso pido vuestra opinión por aquí, ya que a pesar de ser un principiante quiero que mis apps se vean lo más profesionales posible.

La cuestión es, qué carpetas debo crear para que las interfaces de mi app se muestren correctamente y con el mismo aspecto en cualquier dispositivo Android?

Comment: Y añadir que estoy utilizando ConstraintLayout para mis interfaces..... las dimensiones de los distintos elementos las estoy expresando en dp..... y para los atributos layout_width y layout_height les he asignado como valor "wrap_content".... aún cumpliendo todo lo anterior sigo viendo como el diseño de algunos layouts varía entre distintos dispositivos Android... está claro que hay detalles que se me escapan, por eso estaba pensando en crear esos nuevos directorios que nombre en mi mensaje anterior, a ver si así logro que mis layouts se vean igual en cualquier dispositivo....

Comment: Dentro del android estudio, puedes crear versiones alternativas de tu diseño, que varian dependiendo del tamaño de pantalla, aqui te dejo el [enlace](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes?hl=es-419#alternative-layouts)

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, pero me ha surgido una nueva duda que explico más abajo, al añadir los nuevos directorios para los distintos tamaños de pantalla, tienes idea qué diablos es eso, a mí es la primera vez que me pasa.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, me he quedado con 6 directorios para manejar mis layouts, los directorios que tengo actualmente son: layout, layout-land, layout-sw320dp, layout-sw480dp, layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp. Pero ahora, cuando voy a un layout cualquiera de mi carpeta layout, en la vista diseño me sale tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, en las otras carpetas la vista diseño para el mismo layout me muestra la pantalla completa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Disculpen mi ignorancia, pero qué diablos es eso? Por qué en los layouts que se encuentran dentro de mi carpeta layout me muestra sólo un pequeño círculo mientras en los del resto de los directorios se me muestran los layouts enteros? He metido la pata en algo?
Esto no me pasaba cuando sólo tenía un único directorio layout.... empezó a pasarme al crear los nuevos directorios y copiar los layouts en cada uno de ellos.

Comment: porque estas trabajando con una plantilla para smartwatch de ahi que tengas lo de WEAR OS, necesitaras crear una plantilla parra telefonos o tablets seguramente,

Comment: Soy tan novato que no sabía que existen varios tipos de vista diseño, recién acbo de averiguarlo.  De todas formas tengo otro problema.... he creado una carpeta layout-land donde he guardado los diseños de mis layouts específicos para la versión landscape.... El problema es que cuando instalo la aplicación en mi teléfono, al girar la pantalla, me sigue mostrando los mismos layouts que para la versión portrait, como si no me reconociera los diseños de la carpeta layout-land.....

Comment: Y también decir que he comprobado que mi teléfono sí detecta los cambios de orientación de pantalla, cuando la pantalla está en vertical la app muestra un toast que dice "Portrait" mientras cuando está en horizontal muestra un toast "Landscape", quiere decir mi movil detecta los cambios de orientación pero sin embargo en landscape no aplica los diseños de mi carpeta layout-land, y eso es lo que me tiene desconcertado... sabes si hay algo que se me esté escapando? Quizás alguna linea de código en la etiqueta activity de mi Manifest.xml? O qué me puede faltar...?

Comment: ah, y un detalle más.... aparte de mi teléfono personal también he probado la app en 3 emuladores distintos de mi Android Studio (2 con API 30 y el otro con API 29) y sigo teniendo también el mismo problema con todos ellos.... quiero decir, lo de que pueda ser problema específico de mi teléfono Samsung queda descartado, pues en los emuladores también me pasa lo mismo,,, está claro que el foco de mi problema es mi proyecto de Android Studio, algo que está mal o me falte en mi código...